# Google Analytics: Many intranet applications, how to efficiently setup and track?

Tags: google-analytics

In my intranet, there are app names like:

```
http://app1/
http://app2/
http://app3/
```

I'd like to setup GA so it'll automatically categorize each app.

Right now, when I look at the `Real-Time` `Overview` I just see `/` when I'd like to see `app1/`, `app2/`, or `app3/`

Wondering if there's an easy way to do this, or if there's a recommended approach to handle this.

Or should each app have its own Tracking ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use one Tracking ID and have all apps viewed under 1 dashboard to look like `app1/default.aspx`, `app2/default.aspx`, etc.:

The `(.*)` means capture all in `Hostname` and `Request URI`, which means this `http://hostname/request-uri.aspx`

Fill out the form like below.

Remember to apply selected views to the appropriate view. It will take about an hour for this filter to be in effect.

[image]